# Why are my Laravel failed jobs not showing up in the failed_jobs table?

Tags: laravel

I followed the docs to create a job and forced failure with this in my handle():

```
throw new \Exception("Error Processing the job", 1);
```

The result is a failed job as expected, but the failed job is not showing up in the failed_job table. When processing, it is showing up in the jobs table.

```
[2020-12-15 07:37:18][6] Processing: App\Jobs\IntroEmailJob
[2020-12-15 07:37:18][6] Failed:     App\Jobs\IntroEmailJob
```

Laravel 8.0

EDIT:
Found this in the logs:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'uuid' doesn't have a default value
```

I created the failed_jobs table just as the docs explained:

```
php artisan queue:failed-table

php artisan migrate
```

Comment: It will only be written to the `failed_jobs` table after all the retries have been exhausted, how many retries do you allow? You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs).

Comment: 1 try: (php artisan queue:work --tries=1). Still no entry in table. BTW, what is the default number of tries?

Comment: @mjpsr11 the default since Laravel 6.0 is to try once. Older versions of Laravel tried indefinitely (although usually causing database value exceptions after 255 tries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed uuid field in the failed_jobs table to *Null* as default and it's now working.

Can someone explain why the artisan command does not take account for this and what the uuid is used for?

Comment: If you had upgraded an existing project without keeping the `queue.php` config file in sync with the latest releases, and then ran `artisan queue:failed-table` *after* the upgrade, you could end up in a state where your config doesn't have `'driver' =>  'database-uuid'`. Basically you have the newer database schema but an older config, which makes Laravel try to use some behavior from older versions (before the uuid field was added). New projects wouldn't encounter this issue, nor older projects which had published and migrated the failed jobs *before* upgrading (without updating config).

Comment: I'm using Laravel 8.0. Here is my config: `'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database-uuids')`

Comment: is it possible you have something set in the `QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER` environment variable, or perhaps cached configs? (`php artisan config:clear`)

Comment: Reading your comment more carefully, it's possible I have that scenario. I did upgrade Laravel to 8.0 and could have migrated the queue tables after that.

Answer (score 11):

> I changed uuid field in the failed_jobs table to Null as default and it's now working.

You need to add a parameter `driver` with value `database-uuids` in the `~/app/config/queue.php` file because it will be checked [here](https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/master/QueueServiceProvider.php#L264).

```
'failed' => [
    'driver' => 'database-uuids',
    'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```

Then Laravel will use `DatabaseUuidFailedJobProvider` which is able create UUIDs.

Next you will use `php artisan queue:retry YOUR_UUID` for retrying the failed job.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER` environment variable to `database-uuids` will solve your problem, then just do:

```
'failed' => [
    'driver'   => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database-uuids'),
    'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'base'),
    'table'    => 'base.failed_jobs',
],
```

More about helper [env()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-env).

Comment: I believe that is already the default value when the variable is left empty, which might indicate that their config file wasn't setting the `driver` field *at all*, which would mean it's not checking for a  `QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER` variable. Older versions of the queue config that shipped with laravel didn't include the driver field.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Laravel 8 where a record of failed jobs weren't being stored in the "failed_jobs" table.

In my case the issue was that the records weren't being stored because of some kind of UUID / ID issue. Turns out my failed_jobs migration was from Laravel 7.

All you need to do is upgrade this migration to match Laravel 8 or replace this:

```php
$table->uuid('id')->primary();
```

with this:

```php
$table->id();
```