# Laravel Supervisor: Duplicate entry '' for key 'failed_jobs_uuid_unique'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel's Supervisor for queue management, and added the failed_jobs table by using the default commands (`php artisan queue:failed-table` + `migrate`).

A job sometimes fails, but the failed_jobs table is never filled because it apparently tries to add a record without a primary key. I have no idea where in Laravel to have it generate a uuid.

I find issues like `Duplicate entry '014c3080-3ee3-4198-946c-dfe1d8d858a7' for key 'failed_jobs_uuid_unique'`, but that has a different cause. My application doesn't even generate a uuid.

Comment: Please check the config regarding the driver in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307194/why-are-my-laravel-failed-jobs-not-showing-up-in-the-failed-jobs-table). Make sure to clear your config cache after, using `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: What is your Laravel version? As to me, the migration doesn't contain an "uuid" column, but a primary key "BIGINT". Do you have any particular business in the failed() method? Can you try try/catching the job business and log in the catch to see if you can have more details about the job error itself?

Comment: @Sherlock Could you please share the value of `retry_after` and `timeout`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uuid of a Job is generated trough a driver named "**database-uuids**". This should be configured by default inside your **config/queue.php** as following (near the end of the file):

```
'failed' => [
    'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database-uuids'),
    'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```

Unless you have provided another value for **QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER** in your .env file, your failed_jobs should be given a uuid by default.

If this does not work, please leave a comment on this answer and I'll try look for another solution.

Comment: I don't have the 'driver' key in that config array, only 'database' and 'table'. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Sherlock Yes it could very much be why, please try it out and report to me the result :)

Comment: I tried it out but it didnt work

Comment: @Macdonald make sure to clear your config cache after making any changes :)

Answer (score 7):

It seems like Laravel is trying to log the same failed job with the same UUID multiple times. This may happen when two workers pick the same job and both executions fail. The first worker will be able to log the job successfully but the second worker will receive this error because an entry with the same UUID already exists.

check this link for prevent this issue

https://divinglaravel.com/prevent-your-queued-jobs-from-duplicating

Answer (score -1):

Change uuid field nullable at failed_jobs table.